# Javascript add days if it hits on weekend

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry, english is not my mother's tongue.


The code below is when a user selects a date from "date1" for example (1/20/2020) then the script will run which will add 5 Days then it will be like: (1/25/2020) on "date2". Now I want is to detect if it hits on Saturday it should add +2 and if its on Sunday it should +1 day.


Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML Code:

```
<input type="date" onchange="setSecondDate();" id="date1" />
<input type="date" id="date2" />
```

Javascript Code:

```
function setSecondDate() {
  var days = 5;
  var date = new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  document.getElementById('date2').valueAsDate = date;
}
```

Comment: use the date [getDay method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) - adding 1 or 2 days if the result is 0 or 6 respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose just before the last line, you can add the following

```
if(date.getDay() == 0)
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
else if(date.getDay() == 6)
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2)
```

Keeping it simple.